# Delay execution inside a react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I´m calling my search function on every keystroke.
I´m looking for a way to delay this in order to wait for more characters before calling the service.

```
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        keyword && searchService(keyword).then(res => console.log(res));
    }, [keyword]);

    <input
        type="search"
        value={keyword}
        onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
    />
```

what are some good techniques to achieve this?

Comment: debouncing and/or throttling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce

```
const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
```

const [value] = useDebounce(keyword, 1000);

useEffect(() => {

}, [value]);